# Swift: There is way to debug decodable object quickly

Tags: json, swift, codable

I have an object from 20 fields. When I get the json from the server I get an error about the decode of the json.

There is a way to quickly find out which field is problematic instead of deleting all the fields and putting it back one after the other to find out which one is problematic.

Comment: Print the error message (and don't use optional properties unless they really are optional).

Comment: I printed error.localizedDescription it was my error

Comment: Be more specific and print the error

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you're using **`Codable`** to parse your *JSON*, you can simply print the `error` in `catch` block and it will print the complete details of where the issue exist.

```
do {
    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
    print(response)
} catch {
    print(error) //here.....
}
```

Comment: Then the problem might be with the JSON. It might be invalid. Use https://jsonformatter.org to validate your JSON.

Answer (score 22):

You can also add additional catch blocks to understand exactly what is the nature of the error.

```
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let messages = try decoder.decode(Response.self, from: data)
    print(messages as Any)
} catch DecodingError.dataCorrupted(let context) {
    print(context)
} catch DecodingError.keyNotFound(let key, let context) {
    print("Key '\(key)' not found:", context.debugDescription)
    print("codingPath:", context.codingPath)
} catch DecodingError.valueNotFound(let value, let context) {
    print("Value '\(value)' not found:", context.debugDescription)
    print("codingPath:", context.codingPath)
} catch DecodingError.typeMismatch(let type, let context) {
    print("Type '\(type)' mismatch:", context.debugDescription)
    print("codingPath:", context.codingPath)
} catch {
    print("error: ", error)
}
```

Comment: my error camed from an enum Codable where `case clear` where not able to be matched with the server returning me it uppercased `"main": "Clear"`
the solution was highlighted thanks to your answer, by simply adding the case String value as so `case clear = "Clear"`

Answer (score 5):

Just print the `error` instance (**never** `error.localizedDescription`) in the `catch` block.

The error displays the `CodingPath` and the affected key where the error occurs.